# Configuring a Port for Confluence on Google Compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, confluence, portforwarding

I have installed Confluence on a Google Compute Engine Instance. Following is the configuration file for the server.

```
<Server port="8000" shutdown="SHUTDOWN" debug="0">
   <Service name="Tomcat-Standalone">
        <Connector  port="8090" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"
                maxThreads="200" minSpareThreads="10"
                enableLookups="false" acceptCount="10" debug="0" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
        <Engine name="Standalone" defaultHost="localhost" debug="0">
            <Host name="localhost" debug="0" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false">
                <Context path="" docBase="../confluence" debug="0" reloadable="false" useHttpOnly="true">
                    <!-- Logger is deprecated in Tomcat 5.5. Logging configuration for Confluence is specified in confluence/WEB-$
                    <Manager pathname="" />
                </Context>
            </Host>
        </Engine>
```

But I can't access the web gui when i type

```
http://<IP_address>:<port_number>
```

I have tried redirecting using iptable too.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT
 --to-port 8090
```

Comment: For me I had to wait a ridiculous amount of time, I'm not sure how long as I went to bed and in the morning was able to access the setup page.

Comment: I answered to a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61289948/mongosocketreadexception-prematurely-reached-end-of-stream-while-connecting-mo/76868718#76868718

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Go to your [Google cloud console](https://console.developers.google.com)
- Click on your project
- Navigate to Compute -> Compute Engine -> Networks
- Create a new firewall rule with source ip range from anywhere (0.0.0.0/0) to target tags 'Confluence' and your desired port and protocol

[image]

- Navigate to Compute -> Compute Engine -> VM instances
- select your instance and add the 'Confluence' tag

Comment: I used port 8090 and 8000 and it worked, but I had to wait a long time before the setup page showed. Also Port 8000 may not be necessary but I haven't tested. 8090 is the default for confluence, 8080 is the default for jira.