# Google Cloud Mongo DB: External IP not connecting

Tags: mongodb, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have created a ready to go MongoDB server on Google Cloud using the default parameters. Everything is working fine between them (there is communication and I can add DBs and collections). However, I can't connect to MongoDB on any external machine.
I created the firewall rules in GCP allowing all the connections ("0.0.0.0./0") on the port 27017.

I am running the command:

```
giuseppe@ubuntu:~$ mongo --host rs0/104.154.xx.xxx,173.255.xxx.xxx,104.197.xxx.xxx 



giuseppe@ubuntu:~$ mongo --host rs0/104.154.xxx.xxx:27017,173.255.xxx.xxx:27017,104.197.xxx.xxx:27017
```

I'm getting the same error on both of them. I don't know how to resolve this issue.

```js
connecting to: rs0/104.154.41.xxx,173.255.xxx.xxx,104.197.22.xxx:27017/test
2015-03-18T19:47:33.770-0500 starting new replica set monitor for replica set rs0 with seeds 104.154.41.xxx:27017,104.197.22.1xx:27017,xx.255.114.xxx:27017
2015-03-18T19:47:33.770-0500 [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] starting
2015-03-18T19:47:34.119-0500 changing hosts to rs0/mongo-db-jff3:27017,mongo-db-vnc4:27017 from rs0/104.154.41.246:27017,1xx.197.22.xxx:27017,173.255.1xx.xx:27017
2015-03-18T19:47:34.493-0500 getaddrinfo("mongo-db-vnc4") failed: Name or service not known
2015-03-18T19:47:34.511-0500 getaddrinfo("mongo-db-jff3") failed: Name or service not known
2015-03-18T19:47:34.512-0500 Error: connect failed to replica set rs0/104.154.xxx.xxx:27017,173.2xx.xxx.68:27017,104.197.22.xxx:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148
```

**EDIT:**

Here are my firewall settings.

[image]

Comment: What, if any, does this have to do with google-app-engine?  **Why** do people tag so many Qs that way that clearly are **not** GAE questions but have to do with other of the many products in GCP, such as (I suspect here) google-compute-engine?  Do you realize how much harder you're making it for us to offer you free support, when you mis-tag questions like that?!

Comment: I have the same issue with GCP, I set a new firewall rules with the port 27017 with IP ranges 0.0.0.0/0 then i added the target tag in my vm instances. I can connect and view other mongo instances (members) inside instace with SSH, everything works correctly, but outside I can't connect with "mongodb://user:pass@ip-1:27017,ip-2:27017,ip-3:27017/admin?replicaSet=rs-0" only I can connect when I delete de replicaset, "mongodb://user:pass@ip-1:27017,ip-2:27017,ip-3:27017/admin", I dont know why...

Comment: It is the same error described in https://community.bitnami.com/t/mongodb-with-replication-connection-issue-on-gcp/64162/6

Comment: I answered to a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61289948/mongosocketreadexception-prematurely-reached-end-of-stream-while-connecting-mo/76868718#76868718

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you

- configure the firewall rule in Google cloud console
- provide a tag in your firewall rule
- tag your instance with the same tag as the firewall rule

?

I explained how to open a port to the outside world in detail [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28924372/configuring-a-port-for-confluence-on-google-compute-engine/28926336#28926336). Replace with your own port number.

Comment: Yes i did , i've uploaded a picture of my settings

Comment: Or you sure the process is listening on given port ? can you try to do ``netstat -an | grep -i listen | grep tcp`` to verify ?

Comment: firewall rule it was for me

Answer (score 0):

I belive the issue here is that the ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher is changing hosts to rs0/mongo-db-jff3:27017, where mongo-db-jff3 is not reachable from your network. You need to configure the hosts in the replica set to something that you can reach (static IP or URL).

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/change-hostnames-in-a-replica-set/

Quick example, mongo into your PRIMARY (SECONDARY if you want to do it no downtime):

```
cfg = rs.conf()
cfg.members[0].host = "mongodb0.example.net:27017"
cfg.members[1].host = "mongodb1.example.net:27017"
rs.reconfig(cfg)
```