# Timeout error while accessing VNC service in Google Cloud via external IP address

Tags: google-cloud-platform, netcat, vnc

I am running a VNC server in Google Cloud Computing Engine and it is running on port 5901. When I am trying to access the server through below command

nc localhost 5901 I am able to connect.

but when I am trying to connect through external IP which is static and assigned to my cloud console. I am getting timed out error.

I verified the firewall rules and seems everything ok.

Could you please guy help me why this is happening

```
> $ nc localhost 5901 
RFB 003.008 
> $ nc 146.148.91.209 5901 
(UNKNOWN) [146.148.91.209] 5901 (?) : Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer of this question in a different post

There are three steps for that, I was not doing the third one.

1. configure the firewall rule in Google cloud console
2. provide a tag in your firewall rule
3. tag your instance with the same tag as the firewall rule

Comment: I found the solution from below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135528/google-cloud-mongo-db-external-ip-not-connecting?rq=1