# Real VNC not working on Compute Engine in GCP

Tags: vnc-server

Unable to connect with Real VNC to GCE (Ubuntu 18.4) on GCP.

> Error: “Timed out waiting for a response from the host computer”

Created firewall, tags mapping on tcp:5901

Followed this post on stackoverflow: [Google Cloud Mongo DB: External IP not connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135528/google-cloud-mongo-db-external-ip-not-connecting?rq=1)

However, I'm able to connect with putty on external IP with ssh-key.

```
netstat -an | grep -i listen | grep tcp
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6002            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::5901                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::5902                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: Formatting code with a code block makes it easier to read and keeps the formatting. You can do that by intending each line with 4 spaces. Important stuff (like errors) are easier to see if you use a blockquote. Giving links meaningful name further improves readability of your text.

Comment: The issue is resoled by using this $sudo ufw allow 5901